# Firebase AUTHENTICATION_FAILED in some Android devices (java.io.IOException)

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard of our app has been registering this error that occurs only on certain devices, but doesn't show much information about it, also I can't replicate it

```
Fatal Exception: java.io.IOException
AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zza (unknown source:71)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zza (unknown source:84)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.then (unknown source:4)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run (unknown source:5)
```

[image]

We are using these versions of firebase:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
```

The device date is correct and there are no connection issues, as some StackOverflow answers suggest

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here -

It looks like your crashes are not being deobfuscated properly, and so they're showing up with these obfuscated method names. Make sure that you've configured Gradle according [these rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this error with some emulators which doesn't have google services attached.

please try again on a real device.